# WinRT XAML Applying Style Inside DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have some styles that are being included in a page with a resource reference.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have named styles for `TextBlock`, `Button`, etc. When using them, everything works fine.

When I try using them inside of a `DataTemplate` of an `ItemsControl`, they don't get applied.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="blah" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I get the named styles that are included from another file to work inside my `DataTemplate` like it does everywhere else on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the styles in a particular page's XAML, include them in `App.xaml`. Here's how I add them

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="using:MyApp">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I use style defined in `Resources.xaml` in `DataTemplate` all the time.

Comment: All my code is in another assembly that several projects use. Having the app setup xaml for a single page in another assembly doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: Talking of different assemblies, did you try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2015/02/09/how-to-link-style-resource-dictionaries-located-in-different-assemblies-in-winrt.aspx)?

Comment: I have `Shared.dll`. This assembly contains the `Page.xaml` and `MyStyles.xaml`. There is another application that is including this assembly. It works just fine for everything on the page until inside of the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining manually you can use Blend to through design panel.

When you right click to your

> Gridview > Edit Additional Templates > Edit Generated Items

[image]

you can edit your content. Then you can select any of your item and define their style on design pane like below

[image]

If you don't see your button, textblock style in right click menu you can check this post to make them reusable 
[Style only works for the first occurence when outside Grid.Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516617/style-only-works-for-the-first-occurence-when-outside-grid-resources/34529017#34529017)

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I don't have Blend installed. I do have the `generic.xaml` and `themeresources.xaml` from the SDK to copy the original XAML from if I need to change it.