# Style only works for the first occurence when outside Grid.Resources?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, uwp

I have a gridview with a data template which includes a togglebutton. The datatemplate for the items in the Gridview has a grid in it, with a stylized togglebutton. The style for the togglebutton is located in Grid.Resources. It works fine, but when I move the style from Grid.Resources to either Page.Resources or App.xaml, the content inside the button that is defined in the style disappears from all except the first occurrence of the button in the gridview. Here is the style:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="teststyle">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.25"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="9" Width="9"  Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Data="M 0,0 -11.78,-11.779 0,-23.561 l 1.061,1.061 -9.97,9.971 21.064,0 0,1.5 -21.064,0 9.97,9.968 L 0,0 Z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here are screenshots of the behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbw2s.jpg The top image is the original one when the style was located in Grid.Resources, and the bottom is when the style gets moved.

Comment: Do you explicitly set the ToggleButton Style to this StaticResource key (in your datatemplate)?

Comment: @igrali Here's what my ToggleButton declaration looks like in the datatemplate: `<ToggleButton   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource teststyle}"  IsChecked="{x:Bind Path=Liked, Converter={StaticResource downvoteconverter},Mode=OneWay}" IsThreeState="False" Command="{x:Bind downvotecommand}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround this behavior by using ContentTemplate in your style instead Content.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.25"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="9" Width="9"  Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Data="M 0,0 -11.78,-11.779 0,-23.561 l 1.061,1.061 -9.97,9.971 21.064,0 0,1.5 -21.064,0 9.97,9.968 L 0,0 Z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Do you know why the behavior is not correct with the Content property?

Comment: Honnestly no :) I am trying to investigate the root cause but didn't find the answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

`Style` can work outside your `DataTemplate`, the problem here is the `Path` you've set as the `Content` of your `ToggleButton`.

XAML resources in `Style` must be shareable (See [XAML resources must be shareable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187273.aspx#xaml_resources_must_be_sharable)):

> For an object to exist in a `ResourceDictionary`, that object must be ***shareable***.
>
> Being shareable is required because, when the object tree of an app is constructed and used at run time, objects cannot exist at multiple locations in the tree. Internally, the resource system creates copies of resource values to use in the object graph of your app when each XAML resource is requested.

But `UIElement` can never be shareable and `Path` inherits from `UIElement` so `Path` is not shareable. When setting your `Style` in `DataTemplate` and putting the `Style` outside the `DataTemplate`, every `ToggleButton` in the items do  apply the `Style`, but the `Path` can only displays once as it's not shareable. To test it, you can add a object in your `Style` like:

```
<Style x:Key="teststyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Path Width="9"
                  Height="9"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Data="M 0,0 -11.78,-11.779 0,-23.561 l 1.061,1.061 -9.97,9.971 21.064,0 0,1.5 -21.064,0 9.97,9.968 L 0,0 Z"
                  Fill="Black"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1.25">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" />
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Then you will find all the backgrounds of your `ToggleButton` become red. Also you can directly put two `ToggleButton` in a `StackPanel` like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource teststyle}" />
    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource teststyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

You can also find only the first `ToggleButton` have the path.

And when you put the `Style` inside `DataTemplate`, every item will has its own `Resources`, so it works fine.

If you use `ContentTemplate` like @Jean-Sébastien Dupuy said, then the `Value` become a `DataTemplate` which is shareable as it's derived from `FrameworkTemplate`, so it also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to move your styles in XAML is using Blend designer.

You can view and organize your styles from Resources section in Blend. After that you can drag and drop your local style into App.xaml or Resources.xaml. All references will be updated automatically, you can check from below gif image.

[image]

Comment: Tried this. Still same problem :(